# Complicated many-to-many relationship in dropdown search using AngularUI Select

Tags: angularjs, drop-down-menu, angular-ui-select

Can't figure it out! What I'd like to achieve is to be able to filter the source so that another dropdown will use it but with fewer data.

For example, I typed in Adam on the first dropdown, the 2nd and 3rd dropdowns will only have 2 rows for their searches.

Here is a snippet from the html which you'll see in the plunker

```
<p>Selected: {{person.filter1}}</p>
<ui-select ng-model="person.filter1" theme="select2" ng-disabled="disabled" style="min-width: 300px;">
  <ui-select-match placeholder="firstname">{{$select.selected.firstname}}</ui-select-match>
  <ui-select-choices repeat="person in people | propsFilter: {firstname: $select.search}">
    <div ng-bind-html="person.firstname | highlight: $select.search"></div>
  </ui-select-choices>
</ui-select>

<p>Selected: {{person.filter2}}</p>
<ui-select ng-model="person.filter2" theme="select2" ng-disabled="disabled" style="min-width: 300px;">
  <ui-select-match placeholder="company">{{$select.selected.company}}</ui-select-match>
  <ui-select-choices repeat="person in people | propsFilter: {company: $select.search}">
    <div ng-bind-html="person.company | highlight: $select.search"></div>
  </ui-select-choices>
</ui-select>

<p>Selected: {{person.filter3}}</p>
<ui-select ng-model="person.filter3" theme="select2" ng-disabled="disabled" style="min-width: 300px;">
  <ui-select-match placeholder="age">{{$select.selected.age}}</ui-select-match>
  <ui-select-choices repeat="person in people | propsFilter: {age: $select.search}">
    <div ng-bind-html="person.age"></div>
  </ui-select-choices>
</ui-select>
```

Here is a plunker that you can play with 
http://plnkr.co/edit/soaP2RFE8ordXkD9nbLN?p=preview

Comment: What is the specific question? What should we see in demo and what steps would replicate whatever the problem is?

Comment: I mentioned that if I put string Adam in the first dropdown, the 2nd and 3rd dropdown's data source will be reduced down to 2 rows since I've filtered it. However, can't figure out how to do it. The data source for 2nd and 3rd dropdown are still full data. If I started typing first on the 3rd column, the same thing should happen in 1st and 2nd dropdowns.

Comment: `cont -- here is an example. Let's say I typed Adam on first dropdown. The 2nd and 3rd dropdown data source will only be able to search from 2 rows,    { firstname: 'Adam',      company: 'Microsoft', age: '10' },
    { firstname: 'Adam',    company: 'Cisco', age: '12' },

Comment: I got it working. I'm making a copy of the source and then trimming it after I select a value.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways you can achieve this... You can either pass in a second filter via your custom filter you have made there or you can use the built-in filtering that ng-repeat supports alongside the ui-select by simply splitting up each value  you intend to filter with a comma. An example is below:

```
  <p>Selected: {{person.filter1}}</p>
  <ui-select ng-model="person.filter1" theme="select2" ng-disabled="disabled" style="min-width: 300px;">
    <ui-select-match placeholder="firstname">{{$select.selected.firstname}}</ui-select-match>
    <ui-select-choices repeat="person in people | propsFilter: {firstname: $select.search}">
      <div ng-bind-html="person.firstname | highlight: $select.search"></div>
    </ui-select-choices>
  </ui-select>

  <p>Selected: {{person.filter2}}</p>
  <ui-select ng-model="person.filter2" theme="select2" ng-disabled="disabled" style="min-width: 300px;">
    <ui-select-match placeholder="company">{{$select.selected.company}}</ui-select-match>
    <ui-select-choices repeat="person in people | filter: {company: person.filter1.company}">
      <div ng-bind-html="person.company | highlight: $select.search"></div>
    </ui-select-choices>
  </ui-select>

  <p>Selected: {{person.filter3}}</p>
  <ui-select ng-model="person.filter3" theme="select2" ng-disabled="disabled" style="min-width: 300px;">
    <ui-select-match placeholder="age">{{$select.selected.age}}</ui-select-match>
    <ui-select-choices repeat="person in people | filter: {age: person.filter1.age}">
      <div ng-bind-html="person.age"></div>
    </ui-select-choices>
  </ui-select>
```

Just be sure that you are matching the second filter to the correct attribute of the item in the ng-repeat (I mention ng-repeat instead of repeat because ui-select makes use of the ng-repeat rather than options).

EDIT: Here is your example: http://plnkr.co/edit/fvUnpCtwiRfI4VkH6RC9?p=preview

Comment: Thank you. I see a bug. I picked Adam from the first dropdown. Then I clicked the second dropdown and I only saw one entry. There should be 2 since there are 2 Adam entries. It should show Microsoft and Cisco.